# Nextflow: cannot get file pairs from Channel.fromFilePairs

Tags: nextflow

I'm remarkably still struggling with some basic `Nextflow` concepts. I'm simply trying to collect all pairs of `.cram` and `.crai` files from a directory using `Channel.fromFilePairs(...)`, but I get no output when I try to `view()` the `Channel`.

**Question:** Why does my `Channel.fromFilePairs(...)` command not return file pairs, but I get a list of files when using `Channel.fromPath(...)`?

As far as I can tell, I'm following the same pattern from the following examples:

1. [Nextflow fromFilePairs](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#fromfilepairs)
2. [.bam/.bai example](https://github.com/nextflow-io/patterns/blob/master/docs/process-per-file-pairs.adoc) (except without the extra code)

#### Code

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

workflow {

    /*
     * Channel.fromPath returns the expected files and prints them to
     * terminal.
     */
    Channel.fromPath('/path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000*.cram')
        | view()
 
    /*
     * Channel.fromFilePairs does not print anything to terminal.
     */
    Channel.fromFilePairs('/path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000*.{cram,crai}')
        | view()
}
```

#### Output (note, no file tuples/pairs)

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.04.3
Launching `pairs.nf` [pensive_plateau] - revision: f917a5c41b
/path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000563-BL-COL-47451BL1_vcpa1.1.cram.crai
/path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000387-BL-COL-38200BL2_vcpa1.1.cram.crai
/path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000018-BL-COL-46250BL1_vcpa1.1.cram.crai
/path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000169-BL-COL-57413BL1_vcpa1.1.cram
/path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000563-BL-COL-47451BL1_vcpa1.1.cram
/path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000387-BL-COL-38200BL2_vcpa1.1.cram
/path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000194-BL-COL-38470BL1_vcpa1.1.cram
/path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000194-BL-COL-38470BL1_vcpa1.1.cram.crai
/path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000169-BL-COL-57413BL1_vcpa1.1.cram.crai
/path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000018-BL-COL-46250BL1_vcpa1.1.cram
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR**, use:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

workflow {

    Channel.fromFilePairs('/path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000*.cram{,.crai}')
        | view()
}
```

Results:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 20.10.0
Launching `xscript.nf` [special_caravaggio] - revision: a4e53657a0
[A-CUHS-CU000169-BL-COL-57413BL1_vcpa1.1, [/path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000169-BL-COL-57413BL1_vcpa1.1.cram, /path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000169-BL-COL-57413BL1_vcpa1.1.cram.crai]]
[A-CUHS-CU000194-BL-COL-38470BL1_vcpa1.1, [/path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000194-BL-COL-38470BL1_vcpa1.1.cram, /path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000194-BL-COL-38470BL1_vcpa1.1.cram.crai]]
[A-CUHS-CU000018-BL-COL-46250BL1_vcpa1.1, [/path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000018-BL-COL-46250BL1_vcpa1.1.cram, /path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000018-BL-COL-46250BL1_vcpa1.1.cram.crai]]
[A-CUHS-CU000387-BL-COL-38200BL2_vcpa1.1, [/path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000387-BL-COL-38200BL2_vcpa1.1.cram, /path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000387-BL-COL-38200BL2_vcpa1.1.cram.crai]]
[A-CUHS-CU000563-BL-COL-47451BL1_vcpa1.1, [/path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000563-BL-COL-47451BL1_vcpa1.1.cram, /path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000563-BL-COL-47451BL1_vcpa1.1.cram.crai]]
```

---

---

When using the [fromFilePairs](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#fromfilepairs) factory method, the trick is to ensure that the pattern you provide can return a *common* prefix in order for the files to be grouped as expected. An easy way to check to see if this is working as expected is to directly call the [readPrefix](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/blob/v21.10.6/modules/nextflow/src/main/groovy/nextflow/Channel.groovy#L523-L585) helper function. For example:

```
test_cram = file('/path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000169-BL-COL-57413BL1_vcpa1.1.cram')
test_crai = file('/path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000169-BL-COL-57413BL1_vcpa1.1.cram.crai')

pattern = '/path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000*.{cram,crai}'

println("My CRAM prefix is: ${Channel.readPrefix(test_cram, pattern)}")
println("My CRAI prefix is: ${Channel.readPrefix(test_crai, pattern)}")
```

You can see that these results do *not* produce a common prefix:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 20.10.0
Launching `script.nf` [lonely_jang] - revision: 428df7e55e
My CRAM prefix is: A-CUHS-CU000169-BL-COL-57413BL1_vcpa1.1
My CRAI prefix is: A-CUHS-CU000169-BL-COL-57413BL1_vcpa1.1.cram
```

But if you change your pattern definition to:

```
pattern = '/path/to/adsp/cram/snd10000/A-CUHS-CU000*.cram{,.crai}'
```

We can check that it returns a common prefix:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 20.10.0
Launching `script.nf` [maniac_volta] - revision: a8acf7b03f
My CRAM prefix is: A-CUHS-CU000169-BL-COL-57413BL1_vcpa1.1
My CRAI prefix is: A-CUHS-CU000169-BL-COL-57413BL1_vcpa1.1
```

Comment: Thanks, @Steve. Very helpful. The `Channel.readPrefix(...)` is a nice test.